# How to reorder array in JSONB type column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

In PostgreSQL table, a JSONB type column, and the value stored inside is an array `[3,6,78,1]`.

What should I do to reorder it like `[1,3,6,78]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unnest the array with `jsonb_array_elements()` and aggregate its sorted elements using `jsonb_agg()`:

```
with the_data(val) as (values ('[3,6,78,1]'::jsonb))

select jsonb_agg(elem order by elem) as val
from the_data
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(val) as arr(elem);

      val      
---------------
 [1, 3, 6, 78]
(1 row)
```

You can use the query in a custom function which will be handy in more complex queries:

```
create or replace function jsonb_sort_array(jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql immutable
as $$
    select jsonb_agg(elem order by elem)
    from jsonb_array_elements($1) as arr(elem)
$$;

with the_data(val) as (values ('[3,6,78,1]'::jsonb))

select jsonb_sort_array(val) as val
from the_data;

      val      
---------------
 [1, 3, 6, 78]
(1 row)
```